# How can i call phtml file into cms page by using widget?

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, widgets, cms-pages

I have a phtml file `mw/news/slider.phtml`.

I would like to use this file at cms page.

So how can i do this by using widget ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code in the content area of the CMS page:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="mw/news/slider.phtml"}}
```

If needed you can replace 'core/template' with another custom block type.

You can't use a custom .phtml template when adding a widget, so inserting the block directly is the right way to do it.

Comment: yep, but i want use widget, your method?

Comment: Are you building a custom extension?

Comment: Here is a tutorial on creating a widget: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-widget-development-in-magento--cms-23015

You'll need to let it extend Mage_Core_Block_Template instead of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, and set the template to the template file you want to use.

Comment: I'd like to show you but I can't explain it better than the blog post. The easiest solution is to just use the block like in my answer.

Comment: Hi Trong Tran Xuan, please accept my answer if it solves you problem. Thanks!

Comment: yeb, but i dont use block code. HWVR thank for support